# Text box pasting issue

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

How can i disallow paste in a textbox if the copied string contains white spaces

Comment: Why don't you just strip the spaces from the string instead of disallowing it altogether?

Comment: +1 on the suggestion by @slugster: it will be easier to do, and most likely lead to a better user experience.

Comment: @ slugster, First of all i need to get the content that has been copied to paste.

Comment: @Mathew: I think you are attacking the problem in the wrong end. What is your real requirement? I interpret that it is to not allow any spaces in the textbox? If so, it is of no interest *how* the text ends up there. Just clean away spaces when the text changes, for whatever reason that may be. That way you will ensure that the text box contains valid input at all times.

Comment: @ Fredrik, What my requirement is there is a textbox in which i dont want to allow paste functionality if the string that is going to be pasted contains whitespace in between characters or at either ends eg. " abc " or "a b" or "a b c" all these type of strings that are going to be pasted must not be allowed.

Comment: @Mathew so whats wrong if you remove spaces youself in javascript.. will that heart user

Comment: @Mathew: so it's OK to have spaces in the string if the user types it in, rather than pastes it?

Answer (score 1):

Anything that has the ability to do this will require javascript - which the user can disable.  You're must better validating server-side, possibly using one of the [validation controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx).

Comment: @edmondson, Sorry for confusing what my requirement is if the string that is going to be pasted conatains white space at both ends or in between. then that string should not be able to paste eg. " abc abc " or "abc abc"

Answer (score 0):

in C# you can handle the textchanged event, and search for a space, and do something if found.
for example error message or clear the text or anything.
That's pretty straight forward

Answer (score 0):

instead of disabling which i don't think is feasible use javascript to validate that the textbox dosen't contain space.

But As sugested by slugester( in comments) here is a snippet in jQuery that removes whitespaces

```
$("#inputID").change(function(event) {
$("#inputID").html = $("#inputID").val().split(' ').join('');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to detect the paste event, you could use delegates to reach that goal.

This might be a start : [Textbox Copy, Cut and Paste Events](http://ezinearticles.com/?Textbox-Copy,-Cut-and-Paste-Events&id=3586591)

Answer (score 0):

You can write some logic in TextChanged event of TextBox.